# Thread from another class in a Producer Consumer with Queue

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, producer-consumer

I would like to implement a for a Consumer Producer implementations. I haven't implemented the consumer yet because I have a problem with the Producer. The purpose is to download some files in the internet. The threads are started inside a method of a custom object. Threads are objects subclassing threading.Thread. Here is the code

downloader_thread.py

```
from threading import Thread

import time


class Downloader(Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, out_queue):
        super(Downloader, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        self.out_queue = out_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            page = self.queue.get()
            if page:
                print "Simulating download"
                print "Downloading page ", page
                time.sleep(3)
                self.out_queue.put(page)

            self.queue.task_done()
```

main_class.py

```
from Queue import Queue

from downloader_thread import Downloader


class Main(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = Queue(0)
        self.out_queue = Queue(0)
        self.threads = []
        self.max_threads = 5

    def download(self):
        page = 1
        for i in range(self.max_threads):
            download_thread = Downloader(self.queue, self.out_queue)
            download_thread.setDaemon(True)
            download_thread.start()
            self.threads.append(download_thread)

        while page < 100:
            self.queue.put(page)
            page += 1

        self.queue.join()

        for thread in self.threads:
            thread.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main = Main()
    main.download()
    while not main.out_queue.empty():
        print main.out_queue.get()
```

Problem is that the thread is started normally all five of them, they perform what is in the run method, but the don't stop, so the while never gets executed. I am kinda new to thread and concurrent programming, so please be gentle :)

The point is to have a consumer thread dealing with the while part of code instead of having this while in the "**main**": part of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your threads never terminate, as they have a `run()` method with an infinite loop. In your `download()` method you [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) to those threads:

```
        for thread in self.threads:
            thread.join()
```

and so the program is blocked. Just remove the joins, as it seems you've meant for those threads to persist during the program's lifetime.

Comment: Thank you for you quick response. The job of terminating the threads is taken care of by the queue with the queue.join() and the queue.task_done() correct?

Comment: No, the threads never terminate during the program's lifetime with your current implementation. They do allow terminating the python program, as they're daemonic threads. When `queue` runs out, they sit blocked in `page = self.queue.get()`. You do have it right with `queue.task_done()` and you can `queue.join()`, which is to wait for all items of the queue to be gotten and processed.

Comment: Is there a way to end the threads when download returns with the current implementation? I guess not correct? Is there a way to force them to stop? I heard that it's not a best practice to force stopping a thread correct?

Comment: If you really do need them to stop, make 'em loop on some condition instead of `while True:`, for example. That also requires that you don't block indefinitely in `get()`. Add a timeout and catch and ignore `Queue.Empty`.

Comment: ok...so to sum up...a thread gets destroyed when the callable exits (either run or target). It's the developer's responsiblity to add the logic on how to terminate the thread. Thanks a lot.